# JDBC Glue Connection Test Failed - InvalidInputException: 2 validation errors detected

Tags: aws-glue

I created a new JDBC Glue Connection that points to a SQL Server database:

- Name = `my connection (test)`
- JDBC URL = `jdbc:sqlserver://my-server:1433;databaseName=test`
- Username and password set
- Network options set (VPC, subnet, security group)

When I try to test the connection, I get the following error:

> InvalidInputException: 2 validation errors detected: Value '/aws-glue/testconnection/error/my_connection_

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you cannot use parentheses in the connection name. I changed the connection name from `my connection (test)` to `my connection` and it worked.